# SQL Query to search from a string sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Records in database are as:

```
Code        Description
10021       ABC
10023       ABC
....         ....
10100       ABC

9000A       XYZ
9001B       XYZ
.....       ....
9026Z        XYZ
```

Now i have to search sequence like code from 10021-10100 or from 9000A-9026Z
these are varchar values.
How can I query to get respective ranges of codes

[image: image example]

range search 10021-69990 but records like 1002F also appears which is diff category.

Comment: . . You need to better explain the logic you want implemented.  Based on standard collation, the results are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You would use comparisons:

```
select *
from t
where code >= '10021' and code <= '10100';
```

The comparison values need to be strings.  Are you aware that these work on string values?  The ordering is based on the collation of the strings -- but that is happily usually just alphabetic ordering.

Comment: please see image what i get with this query

Comment: But 1002F is a seperate range in my case any idea to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the STUFF() fonction ! Please see the link :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/biztalk/en-US/d53f6285-5fb8-4656-b3ff-e28aa47d3e90/listagg-function-in-sql-server?forum=databasedesign

Hope that can help.